# What does this do exactly?

Tags: java

```
    public boolean equals(Object a){
    if(this == a){
        return true;
    }
    if(!(a instanceof OrderedDoublePair)){
        return false;
    }
    return (((OrderedDoublePair)a).getx()==this.x && ((OrderedDoublePair)a).gety()==this.y);
}
```

I'm trying to figure out what the line if(this == a) does. I'm creating a new class called OrderedDoublePair that represents an x and y coordinate. This method is supposed to check to see if an object parameter is an OrderedDoublePair and then check to see if the x and y values for each ordereddoublepair are equal to each other. I'm trying to understand what the this == a line tells me.

Comment: "Is `a` the same object as `this`?"

Comment: thats what im trying to find

Comment: Do you know what `==` does, what `this` means and what `a` is?

Comment: this refers to the OrderedDoublePair i have. The parameter Object a represents a variable that may or may not be an ordereddoublepair. This code is supposed to test to see if the object is an ordered double pair and check if the x and y values are equal

Comment: @user2923691 You can take a look at my solution below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this == a` simply checks if `a` *is* the instance on which `equals` was called; i.e. if you had something like:

```
OrderedDoublePair a = ...;
OrderedDoublePair b = a;  // a and b now refer to the same instance of OrderedDoublePair

...

if (a.equals(b)) {  // <---
    ...
}
```

then `this == a` would be true in your snippet. This is more of an optimization than anything, it avoids doing the extra `x` and `y` comparisons if you know you're comparing two things that are actually the *same* thing. You could remove that check and still get the same behavior.

By the way, this is a common idiom in many `equals` methods. For instance, take a look at the first few lines of [`String#equals`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.equals%28java.lang.Object%29):

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: @user2923691 Yes, it certainly looks fine.

Comment: so i could remove the  if(this == a) completely and I would be fine right?

Comment: @user2923691 That's right. Like I said, it's more of an optimization than anything.

Comment: ah okay. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user2923691 Glad I could help. Don't forget to [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 2):

```
this == a
```

is checking whether the two objects being compared for equality are exactly same instance, i.e. both a and this are two references to the same object.

Comment: That depends. Are you running into any issues? Where is the equals method written? I suppose inside OrderedDoublePair class. What is the data type of x and y properties? Are they integers or doubles?

Answer (score 0):

This will check if a and this are the same object and not an object that has the same values as a but a different location in memory

Answer (score 0):

Your method, **equals**, would be used in an expression of the form:
**someObject.equals(someOtherObject)**.

When the method executes, the keyword **this** refers to the object **someObject** and the parameter **a** refers to the object **someOtherObject**
The code **if (this == a)** will determine if **someObject** and **someOtherObject** are the same object, that is, point to the same memory location.

The **==** operator only compares the contents of the memory locations of its operands, i.e., **this** and **a**. Since **this** and **a** are both references to objects, they hold memory addresses.

Answer (score 0):

When both variables are pointing at the same instance, your code `if(this == a)` will return **true**.

```
+-----+
| obj | <--- objA 
+-----+ <--- this (this refers to your current object)

//(this==a) will return TRUE
```

If it is this case as below, it will return **false** (Even both instance may contain the exact same values in their members).

```
+------+
| obj1 | <--- objA 
+------+ 
+------+
| obj2 | <--- this
+------+ 

 //(this==a) will return FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

This function equals() is to define a specific way to compare two object whether they are equal to each other:

1) if they are the same thing (object), then we say they are equal.

2) if the input a is not an object of class OrderedDoublePair, then not equal.

3) otherwise, if and only if the two OrderedDoublePair objects have same x and y,
  then they are equal